# How to get URL of active tab from popup.js with Safari iOS App Extension in iOS 15?

Tags: javascript, swift, safari-extension, ios15, safari-app-extension

I'm developing Safari App Extension for iOS 15.0+ and I need to get URL of active tab in popup.js and display.

Here is how I do that in popup.js:

```
document.getElementById("appresponse").innerHTML = safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.url;
```

As result it returns nothing.

Also I tried

> document.getElementById("appresponse").innerHTML = document.URL

but it returns path to current popup.js file.

Here is my permissions from manifest.json:

```
"permissions": ["nativeMessaging", "activeTab"]
```

And info.plist:

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>10</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.Safari.web-extension</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SafariWebExtensionHandler</string>
</dict>
```